# Adjusting arrows in this diagram

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=huge]
Hom_{\Gamma}(\mathcal{B}(G),A)\arrow{r}{\rho}\arrow{rd}
& Hom_{\Delta}(\mathcal{B}(G),A)\arrow{d}{i^{*}}\\
& Hom_{\Gamma}(\mathcal{B}(G),A)
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

but I want the slanted arrow to go at the H of Hom by its left and not above it. How do I fix it?

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages and the definition of `\Hom` if the command isn't defined in a package.

Comment: actually, \Hom is just to print Hom as not written in math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `end anchor` key. Either

```
\arrow[rd, end anchor=west]
```

[image]

Or,

```
\arrow[rd, end anchor=north west]
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=huge]
Hom_{\Gamma}(\mathcal{B}(G),A)\arrow{r}{\rho}\arrow[rd, end anchor=west]
& Hom_{\Delta}(\mathcal{B}(G),A)\arrow{d}{i^{*}}\\
& Hom_{\Gamma}(\mathcal{B}(G),A) 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think `north west` would look better

Comment: @Bernard OP Yes. It looks better. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think TikZ is plainer.

[image]

```
%\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
(0,0)    node (L) {$Hom_{\Gamma}(\mathcal{B}(G),A)$}
++(0:4)  node (C) {$Hom_{\Delta}(\mathcal{B}(G),A)$}
+(-90:2) node (B) {$Hom_{\Gamma}(\mathcal{B}(G),A)$};
\draw[->] (L)--(C) node[midway,above]{$\rho$};
\draw[->] (C)--(B) node[midway,right]{$i^{*}$};
\draw[->] (L)--(B.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Approved also your code. Very nice.